# how to over come "Failed to create COM object `word.application': Invalid syntax" when instanciated COM....?

Tags: php, com, ms-office

I am trying to convert a word document to text and I use below code for it:

```
public function executeManoj() { 
$filename='C:\xampp\htdocs\branch.com\web\greenwich-beer-and-jazz-application-form.doc';    
$TXTfilename = $filename . ".txt";

$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word object");
$word->Documents->Open($filename);

// the '2' parameter specifies saving in txt format
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($TXTfilename ,2);
$word->Documents[1]->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
$word->Release();
$word = NULL;
unset($word);

$content = file_get_contents($TXTfilename);
//unlink($TXTfilename);
exit;
}
```

But it is resulting in error saying

> "Failed to create COM object `word.application': Invalid syntax"....

I have set 'Allow service to interact with the desktop' in xammp ticked.

Do I need to install any software before it?

Comment: Assuming you have Office installed - what happens if you load the type library just before you do `$word = new COM`. So add this line just above `com_load_typelib('Word.Application');`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48498), it seems that `word.application` isn't installed on your machine. Try to install it first (don't know where to find it ...).

Comment: Pls some body tell me how to install word application on my system. I am using windows xp home edition and xampp server

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22276). Please use [Google](http://www.google.fr/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Failed+to+create+COM+object+word.application) ....

Comment: Word.application is a part of MS Office. But I am afraid it will not help. I have the same problem with MS Office installed. Try to run your script from commandline (php yourfile.php). In my case it works fine, but not under Apache.